# quick brew recipes

Tags: ingredients, recipe

What quick brews are there? ~ 2 weeks from start to drink...

Should be simple, boozy and tasty. any type of fruits or roots will do! so far have mainly tried a ginger beer, cider and elderflower all with reasonably good results.

now looking for new ideas...

Comment: I'm not certain that recipe requests are appropriate here.

Comment: its not so much a recipe request, more a question about what can be brewed quickly with good results

Answer (score 1):

Many beers can be brewed this fast. Lower gravity beers and beers that don't need any sort of aging are good bets. Cloning Black Tuesday will take a little longer than 2 weeks.

Adding more yeast during the fermentation will help speed up the process. When I've had to push a beer through quickly in the past, I've added [Safale 05](http://www.northernbrewer.com/default/safale-us-05-american.html) a few days into the fermentation. It doesn't add much flavor past whatever yeast you use originally, and will kick things up a notch.

One thing that will significantly speed up the process is a kegging system. If you force carbonate the beer, you can skip that whole 10 day bottle conditioned part.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're going to need to force carb as there is no way bottle conditioning will work in time.  I've done an English mild and also a blonde ale both that came out fine after 2 weeks.  The blonde was a bit hazy though that cleared up after some time in the keg.  Essentially I would say anything you can keep at 4.0% abv or less would be a good candidate.  Hefeweizens are great candidates for this treatment since they are better young and are hazy by nature.  I'd stay away from IPAs since you'd want a stronger, sweeter beer to hold up to the hops.